# create new column based on conditional of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table which shows the hour, total, and km_length:

```
type   hour  km_length   total 
A       1                  1
B               2          1
```

I want to add column which shows the rate. Rate can be calculated by two columns with 2 situations:

```
(1) rate = (hour x 100) / total
```

```
(2) rate = (km_length x 1000000) / total
```

When the row has value on hour, then it will use the first equation. If the row has value on km_length, then it will use the second equation.

then the table will be like this:

```
type    hour     km_length    total    rate
A        1                      1      100
B                    2          1      2000000
```

is there anyway I can make it by using python?

thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you're looking for combining those cases into one equation. If so, use `np.nan_to_num()` function :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A','B'],'hour': [1,np.NaN], 'km_length': [np.NaN,2], 'total' : [1,1]})
df['rate'] = ( np.nan_to_num(df['hour'])*100 + np.nan_to_num(df['km_length'])*1000000 ) / df['total']
print(df)

  type  hour  km_length  total       rate
0    A   1.0        NaN      1      100.0
1    B   NaN        2.0      1  2000000.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.bfill` with `axis==1`:

```
# df = df.replace("", np.nan) # In case it's whitespace(s) instead of np.nan
df["hour"] = df["hour"] * 100
df["km_length"] = df["km_length"] * 1000000
df["rate"] = df.bfill(1)["hour"]/df["total"]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  type   hour  km_length  total   rate
0    A  100.0        NaN      1    100
1    B    NaN  2000000.0      1  2e+06
```